# Animation triggers the second time in safari browser

Tags: css, animation, svg, safari, transition

I have the following animation:
when page is loaded, animation is being triggered to show 3 ellipses. Also you are able to play animation when you hover on svg element. If you click on button, there is also animation.

It is good everywhere, except Safari browsers. It plays 2 time when page is being loaded. it's because of adding SHOWN class and TRANSITION property.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                   function func() {
            document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].classList.add("shown");
        }

        setTimeout(func, 1000); 
    </script>
<div class="container">    
    <div class="svg">

        <svg width="588px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 588 512" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <defs>
                <radialGradient cx="96.4297259%" cy="15.499442%" fx="96.4297259%" fy="15.499442%" r="80.0645369%" gradientTransform="translate(0.964297,0.154994),scale(0.597701,1.000000),rotate(111.076207),translate(-0.964297,-0.154994)" id="radialGradient-1">
                    <stop stop-color="#1796FE" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#1796FF" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
                <radialGradient cx="96.4297259%" cy="15.499442%" fx="96.4297259%" fy="15.499442%" r="80.0645369%" gradientTransform="translate(0.964297,0.154994),scale(0.597701,1.000000),rotate(111.076207),translate(-0.964297,-0.154994)" id="radialGradient-2">
                    <stop stop-color="#00D2CE" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#1796FF" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
                <path d="M0.201171875,0.338867188 L7.65917969,53.88204 C16.8297526,92.6273467 49.4951172,112 105.655273,112 C161.81543,112 195.925456,96.1250885 207.985352,64.3752655 L216.59668,0.338867188 L0.201171875,0.338867188 Z" id="path-3"></path>
                <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="97.0264668%" y2="98.5132334%" id="linearGradient-5">
                    <stop stop-color="#1796FF" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#141935" offset="100%"></stop>
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient x1="91.1850287%" y1="8.8149713%" x2="0%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-6">
                    <stop stop-color="#0084FF" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#25CADF" offset="100%"></stop>
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-7">
                    <stop stop-color="#008CFF" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#141935" stop-opacity="0.840013587" offset="100%"></stop>
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient x1="58.8362069%" y1="0%" x2="4.1697535%" y2="92.9129464%" id="linearGradient-8">
                    <stop stop-color="#546EFF" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#00FFFB" offset="100%"></stop>
                </linearGradient>
                <radialGradient cx="50%" cy="80.5791796%" fx="50%" fy="80.5791796%" r="68.1773364%" gradientTransform="translate(0.500000,0.805792),scale(0.864964,1.000000),rotate(-90.000000),scale(1.000000,0.821060),translate(-0.500000,-0.805792)" id="radialGradient-9">
                    <stop stop-color="#04CAD5" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#651FFF" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
                <path d="M214,237 L274,0 L0,0 L60,237 C60,211.594902 94.4740743,191 137,191 C179.525926,191 214,211.594902 214,237 Z" id="path-10"></path>
                <pattern id="pattern-11" width="512" height="512" x="-512" y="-512" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <use xlink:href="#image-12"></use>
                </pattern>
                <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%" id="linearGradient-13">
                    <stop stop-color="#1796FF" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#00D2CE" offset="100%"></stop>
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-14">
                    <stop stop-color="#0084FF" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#1C2340" offset="100%"></stop>
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-15">
                    <stop stop-color="#1796FF" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#00C6C2" offset="100%"></stop>
                </linearGradient>
                <radialGradient cx="91.4953348%" cy="21.0272753%" fx="91.4953348%" fy="21.0272753%" r="64.3551638%" gradientTransform="translate(0.914953,0.210273),rotate(136.562683),scale(1.000000,2.219463),translate(-0.914953,-0.210273)" id="radialGradient-16">
                    <stop stop-color="#00D2CE" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#1796FF" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
                <radialGradient cx="92.7238408%" cy="19.2250741%" fx="92.7238408%" fy="19.2250741%" r="67.5736129%" gradientTransform="translate(0.927238,0.192251),rotate(134.212462),scale(1.000000,1.464800),translate(-0.927238,-0.192251)" id="radialGradient-17">
                    <stop stop-color="#00D2CE" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#651FFF" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
                <linearGradient x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-18">
                    <stop stop-color="#536EFF" offset="0%"></stop>
                    <stop stop-color="#25CADF" offset="100%"></stop>
                </linearGradient>
                <filter x="-42.9%" y="-56.0%" width="185.7%" height="211.9%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="filter-19">
                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="50" in="SourceGraphic"></feGaussianBlur>
                </filter>
            </defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g id="1440x900" transform="translate(-437.000000, -103.000000)">
                    <g id="illustration" transform="translate(556.000000, 161.000000)">
                        <g id="clock_bottom_1" class="clock_bottom_1">
                            <ellipse id="Oval" fill="url(#radialGradient-1)" transform="translate(87.000000, 52.000000) rotate(-180.000000) translate(-87.000000, -52.000000) " cx="87" cy="52" rx="87" ry="52"></ellipse>
                            <ellipse id="Oval" fill="url(#radialGradient-2)" transform="translate(117.000000, 52.000000) scale(-1, 1) rotate(-180.000000) translate(-117.000000, -52.000000) " cx="117" cy="52" rx="87" ry="52"></ellipse>
                        </g>
                        <g id="clock_bottom_2" class="clock_bottom_2" opacity="0.318917572">
                            <ellipse id="Oval" fill="url(#radialGradient-1)" transform="translate(87.000000, 52.000000) rotate(-180.000000) translate(-87.000000, -52.000000) " cx="87" cy="52" rx="87" ry="52"></ellipse>
                            <ellipse id="Oval" fill="url(#radialGradient-2)" transform="translate(117.000000, 52.000000) scale(-1, 1) rotate(-180.000000) translate(-117.000000, -52.000000) " cx="117" cy="52" rx="87" ry="52"></ellipse>
                        </g>
                        <g id="clock_bottom_3" class="clock_bottom_3" opacity="0.316786674">
                            <ellipse id="Oval" fill="url(#radialGradient-1)" opacity="0.24" transform="translate(87.000000, 52.000000) rotate(-180.000000) translate(-87.000000, -52.000000) " cx="87" cy="52" rx="87" ry="52"></ellipse>
                            <ellipse id="Oval" fill="url(#radialGradient-2)" opacity="0.24" transform="translate(117.000000, 52.000000) scale(-1, 1) rotate(-180.000000) translate(-117.000000, -52.000000) " cx="117" cy="52" rx="87" ry="52"></ellipse>
                        </g>


                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>

        <div class="text_block">

            <div class="login">

                <button onclick="javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.add('logining')">
                    <span>Login page</span>
                </button>
            </div> 
        </div>

    </div><!--/centered -->  


</div>


.svg {position: absolute; width: 920px; left: 50%; margin-left: -460px; padding-top: 70px; text-align: center;}

.login { font: normal 12px/200% Arial; color: #929bbd; text-align: center; padding-top: 30px;}
.text_block { position: absolute; text-align: center; width: 100%; margin-top: 30px; transition: all 0.4s; animation: timeout 0.4s linear;  animation-delay: 1.3s; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
.login button { width: 140px; height: 40px; border: none; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 4px; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; font: normal 12px Arial; margin-top: 50px; background: rgba(110,190,225,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(110,190,225,1) 0%, rgba(68,121,235,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(110,190,225,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(68,121,235,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(110,190,225,1) 0%, rgba(68,121,235,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(110,190,225,1) 0%, rgba(68,121,235,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(110,190,225,1) 0%, rgba(68,121,235,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(110,190,225,1) 0%, rgba(68,121,235,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6ebee1', endColorstr='#4479eb', GradientType=0 ); transition: all 0.4s;}
.login button:focus { outline: none;}
.login button span { margin: 2px; float: left; width: 136px; height: 36px;background: rgba(76,135,247,1); line-height: 36px;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(76,135,247,1) 0%, rgba(100,177,214,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(76,135,247,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(100,177,214,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(76,135,247,1) 0%, rgba(100,177,214,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(76,135,247,1) 0%, rgba(100,177,214,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(76,135,247,1) 0%, rgba(100,177,214,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(76,135,247,1) 0%, rgba(100,177,214,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c87f7', endColorstr='#64b1d6', GradientType=1 );}
.login button:hover {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 2px rgba(78, 138, 245, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px 2px rgba(78, 138, 245, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px 2px rgba(78, 138, 245, 0.75);}
/* ----------------------- */


.clock_bottom_3, 
.clock_bottom_2, 
.clock_bottom_1 {transition: transform 0.3s; opacity: 0;}


svg:hover .clock_bottom_3 {transform: translate(72px, 320px); }
svg:hover .clock_bottom_2 {transform: translate(72px, 298px); }
svg:hover .clock_bottom_1 {transform: translate(72px, 280px);}


.clock_bottom_3 {transform: translate(72px, 365px); animation: clock_bottom_3 0.5s linear; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
.clock_bottom_2 {transform: translate(72px, 348px); animation: clock_bottom_2 0.5s linear; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
.clock_bottom_1 {transform: translate(72px, 320px); animation: clock_bottom_1 0.5s linear; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}

.shown .clock_bottom_1 { animation: none; transform: translate(72px, 277px); opacity: 1;    transition: all 0.6s;}
.shown .clock_bottom_2 { animation: none; transform: translate(72px, 291px); opacity: 1;    transition: all 0.6s;}
.shown .clock_bottom_3 { animation: none; transform: translate(72px, 306px); opacity: 1;    transition: all 0.6s;}


@keyframes clock_bottom_3 {
    to {transform: translate(72px, 306px); opacity: 1;transition: transform 0.3s;}
}
@keyframes clock_bottom_2 {
    to {transform: translate(72px, 291px); opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes clock_bottom_1 {
    to {transform: translate(72px, 277px); opacity: 1;}
}

/* when you press button */
.logining .clock_bottom_3 {transform: translate(72px, 354px); opacity: 0;}
.logining .clock_bottom_2 {transform: translate(72px, 329px);  opacity: 0;}
.logining .clock_bottom_1 {transform: translate(72px, 300px); opacity: 0;}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fpfmxawv/2/

Comment: Have you already tried using the CSS prefix -webkit-? For example: `-webkit-transition: all 0.6s;`

Comment: It doesn't help